# My site keeps getting rejected by a bot with empty reason & details

Tags: google-adsense

My site submission to Adsense keeps getting rejected by Google bot within an hour with blank reason and details(my first submission on Sunday, this time). When I raised it in Adsense forum, they have me mailed reason - site was down or unavailable.

I submitted a couple of times since Sunday but it gets rejected.
First time my site was rejected due to navigational issues which I corrected. Second time came "Unacceptable contet". I then added Privacy policy & TOS. 
Now all other advertising companies have accepted my site including Citika & Adbrite. What should I do now?
I've another site coming up for approval in Adsense. Should I apply from my father's name?

**Rejection message:**

> We did not approve your application
>   for the reasons listed below.
>
> Issues:
>
> ---
>
> Further detail:
>
> ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read Google Adsense Policies? If not, go read them and try to figure out if your site is violating their policies, if they've sent you "Unacceptable content" as rejection cause, you should review and modify your content.
[Adsense Policies](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=48182)

If your website is not written in english, is your website language supported by Adsense?
[Adsense supported languages](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=9727)